# Why is my chameleon's mouth staying open on one side?

Tags: reptiles, chameleons

It looks like her mouth is going to one side. I don't know what to do. She has never been injured that we are aware of. She always stays in her cage, and she is able to eat.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: In addition to the above ^ picture request, how old is she and what is her feeding regimen?